# numpy range created using percentage increment

Tags: pandas, numpy

I would like to create a numpy range from `start` to `stop` using a (fixed) percentage increment based on the previous number eg start=100 increment=2% to get 100, 102, 104.04, 106.12 etc

Obviously this can be done by iterating over a list or, more elegantly, using a generator:

```
def pct_incrementer(start, stop, step_pct):
    val = start
    yield val
    while True:
        val += val * step_pct
        if val >= stop:
            break
        yield val

 np.array(list(pct_incrementer(100, 200, 0.02)))
 # or (as I've just learned!)
 np.fromiter(pct_incrementer(100, 200, 0.02), float)
```

Does numpy (or pandas) have a function to do this natively??  (cos I can't find one!).  Is there, perhaps a way of manipulating `np.array([100] * 10)` to do the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `full` and `cumprod`:

`xs = 100 * np.full(np.log(2.0)/np.log(1.02),1.02).cumprod()`

Comment: That's a neat answer... I had a feeling there'd be some log trickery that'd do this.  Thank you.

Comment: I will point out, however, that (using %timeit) my np.fromiter(pct_incrementer()) is considerably faster than .full()/,cumprod() using the admittedly small number of values 100-200 @2%

Comment: @user908094 this is interesting. Also, on my machine, most of the slowdown comes from `* 100`. Some googling shows `np.logspace` and `np.geomspace` which could be of use.

Comment: I'd seen these functions (along with np.linspace), I guess I was hoping for a function to which I could pass a lambda which would describe the 'progression' ... pretty complex (impossible?) to implement...

Answer (score 0):

```
xs = 100 * np.full(np.log(2.0)/np.log(1.02),1.02).cumprod()
```

appears to now be throwing an error:

> TypeError 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Updated to:

```
xs = 100 * np.full(int(np.log(2.0)/np.log(1.02)),1.02).cumprod()
```

or more succinctly:

```
xs1 = 100 * np.full(5,1.02).cumprod()
```

resulting

```
array([102. , 104.04  , 106.1208  , 108.243216  , 110.40808032])
```

Comment: This should be chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
start = 120
end = 255
display=[start]
 while True:
    xs1 = start * np.full(1,1.02).cumprod()
    if xs1.item(0)>=end:
        break
    else:
        display.append(xs1.item(0))
        start=xs1.item(0)
display = [ round(elem, 2) for elem in display ]
print(display)

#Result: [120, 122.4, 124.85, 127.34, 129.89, ... 254.68]
```

this method is 20-40 times faster. Hope this helps :)